# Python - remove specific line in string variable

Tags: python

Is it possible in Python to remove only single line from a string variable without doing the concatenation of both chunks? I'm after removing `cachedLength` line.

```
input_columns = f'''\
<inputColumn 
    refId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].Columns[{tbl}]"
    cachedDataType="{dt_type}"
    cachedName="{tbl}"
    cachedLength="{dt_lngh}"
    cachedPrecision="{dt_prc}"
    cachedScale="{dt_scl}"
    externalMetadataColumnId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].ExternalColumns[{tbl}]"
    lineageId="Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[SRC Output].Columns[{tbl}]" />
'''
```

Work in progress:

```
i = input_columns.split("\n")[4]
print(input_columns.replace(i, ""))
```

Comment: Not possible. Strings are immutable in Python.  Use `str.replace` or `re.sub` to create new string instead.

Comment: Your choices are usually: split and rejoin the string, replace a fixed substring with string.replace(), replace with re.sub(), or use a library to manage a particular kind of data (HTML, XML, etc.).

Comment: You can use a combination of str.split and str.join, but I think that would be "concatenating" again.

Comment: What you have is an XML element. You shouldn't  be trying to remove lines from an arbitrarily formatted string; you should parse it, remove an *attribute*, and reserialize the result.

Comment: To be specific, this is XML/DTSX file I need to modify data for. I know there is BIML/EzAPI but they don't support Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the line using `re` module:

```
re.sub(r'\s*cachedLength=".*"', '', input_columns)
```

But as mentioned in the comments, technically, Python will recreate the string because it's an immutable type.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly answering the question, but if modifying the xml is what you're after, you could use a package for that. E.g., using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """\
<inputColumn 
    refId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].Columns[{tbl}]"
    cachedDataType="{dt_type}"
    cachedName="{tbl}"
    cachedLength="{dt_lngh}"
    cachedPrecision="{dt_prc}"
    cachedScale="{dt_scl}"
    externalMetadataColumnId="Package\DFT\DST.Inputs[DST Input].ExternalColumns[{tbl}]"
    lineageId="Package\DFT\SRC.Outputs[SRC Output].Columns[{tbl}]" />
"""

e = etree.fromstring(xml)

del e.attrib["cachedLength"]

print(etree.tostring(e, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode"))
```